# jQuery get Array of all <th> values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I want to obtain an Array of all the inner texts of all `<th>`s in a table.

The following works

`$("th").toArray().map(th => th.innerText)`

Just wondering if there is a better way in straight jQuery (wo having to convert to Array and then use JS methods)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to avoid creating an intermediate array with the `.map`, there's a more *efficient* method without jQuery, which only creates a single array for the output, but it requires more source code:

```
const texts = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('th'),
  th => tx.innerText
);
```

From your original version, you can use jQuery's `.text` by mapping before the `.toArray`:

```js
const texts = $("th").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).toArray();
console.log(texts);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><th>foo</th></tr>
</table>
```

But you probably want to use [`.textContent`](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) instead of `.innerText` instead.

Comment: I didn't know about that second argument to `Array.from()`. That's useful.

Comment: Good to know about Array.from map arg. Why textContent over innerText?

Answer (score 4):

jQuery has its own `.map()` method that will map over a collection. It returns a collection of the results, and you can use `.get()` to convert that to an array at the end.

```
$("th").map((i, el) => el.innerText).get();
```